# Image changes size when I zoom in and out in a window

Tags: html, css, image

I don't know why but my image changes its size when I zoom in or out on my window (chrome). Does anyone know why? This is my code: The css for the image is "myphotointro". Its at the very end of the css and html.
[This normal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWA9N.png)
[This is zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/digxf.png)
If anyone knows what to do It would be greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gethomeworkdone.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navabr1">
        <nav>
            <div class="head__logo">
                <div class="logo">
                  <a class="linklogo" href="http://www.google.com">VovaSite</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="barsection">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="nav-home">
                                <a href="Homepage.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="nav-about">
                                <a href="aboutme.html">About</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="nav-articles">
                                <a href="homeworkdone.html">Homeworkdone</a>
                            </li> 
                        <li class="nav-articles">
                                <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
                            </li> 
                        <li class="nav-articles">
                                <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
                            </li> 
                        <li class="nav-articles">
                                <a href="articles.html">articles</a>
                            </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="backroundcolourthing-gethomeworkdone">
  <div class="sectionintro">
    <div class="sectionleft">
        <h1 class="introphrase1"> Need a break from Homework? </h1>
        <p class="introphrase2"> Got tired of all-nighters? Let others do it for you ! </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a  style="text-decoration:none" href="homeworkexchange.html" class="butten">Yourhomeworkdone</a>  
    </div>
    <div class="sectionphotoright">
        <img class="myphotointro" alt="Pacific" src="imgintro.jpg" >
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
nav {
    display: flex; /* 1 */
    justify-content: space-between; /* 2 */
    padding: 1rem 2rem; /* 3 */
    background: rgb(247, 251, 255);;/* 4 */ 
    
}


  nav ul {
    display: flex; /* 5 */
    list-style: none; /* 6 */
    margin: auto;
  }

  
  nav li {
    padding-left: 3rem; /* 7! */
    margin: 3%;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }


  nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif light ;
}

    .barsection {
      margin-right: right;
    }


    
.linklogo {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 25px;
    display: flex; /* 1 */
    justify-content: space-between; /* 2 */
    padding: 1rem 2rem; /* 3 */
  }

  #backroundcolourthing-gethomeworkdone {
    background-color:rgb(247, 251, 255);;
    padding: 10px ;
    border: 0px solid green ;
    width: auto;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .sectionleft {
    position: relative;
    left: -280px;
    top: 50px;
  }

.introphrase1 {
    font-family: optima;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.895);
    text-align: center;
    
}

.introphrase2 {
    font-family: optima;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.895);
    text-align: center;
}



.myphotointro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: -8em auto;
  margin-left: 60em;
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 20%;
}

 .butten {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 30%;
  background-color:#618fecac;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.726);
  border:none; 
  border-radius:20px; 
  padding:15px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I tried a lot but I don't know

Answer (score 0):

It is bcz you **set up width in percentage**. If you do not want to change it with zoom in/out, you need to use px unit. Also max-width is relative bcz, if you change resulotion, it will change width of image.

```
.myphotointro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: -8em auto;
  margin-left: 60em;
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the image's absolute size stays the same no matter the zoom level, and that is because you have specified a width in percentage. Change this to a `px` or `em` value that looks approximately the same at the default zoom level.

The layout is still broken when zooming out though, and that is because your image has a left margin in an `em` size. For a quick fix, I recommend using a percentage value here instead, maybe something like `margin-left: 60%;`.